# How do i use bootstrap with react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, bootstrap-5

I have created a simple web page which includes a header and a footer. I have created the header components with bootstrap, however the bootstrap is not working.

App.js:

```html
import React from "react";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header></Header>
      <main>
        <Container>
          <h1>Welcome to my Website</h1>
        </Container>
      </main>
      <Footer></Footer>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Header.js:

```html
import React from "react";
import { Navbar, Container, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap'

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header>
      <Navbar bg="light" variant="dark" expand="lg" collapseOnSelect>
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand href="">Turini</Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            <Nav.Link href="">Home</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="">Link</Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

package.json:

```html
{
  "name": "react-image-website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "mdb-react-ui-kit": "^6.0.0",
    "mdbreact": "^5.2.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.4",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

The header is displayed on the page as normal HTML and not with Bootstrap. Could someone help me why the bootstrap is not working?

Comment: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#stylesheets

Answer (score 1):

Did you try **importing Bootstrap CSS** in your **index.js file** (the entry point of your application) like this:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```